# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: dns

I am getting this error, when I tried to visit my newly setup site. I tried DNS check tools and I see that there are several errors with DNS configuration.

In dnsstuff.com, I am getting these error messages:

1. Nameservers were found, but the domain entered is a non-delegating subdomain.
2. No nameservers provided an SOA record for the zone. You should configure your nameservers to have a master slave relationship.

link: http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=hostname&&value=www.simpaticorp.com

With Pingdom tools I am getting these error:

1. Delegation not found at parent.

No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet.

2. Not enough nameserver information was found to test the zone, but an IP address lookup succeeded in spite of that.

I am new to DNS configuration. I read few tutorials. It looks like I need to configure NS records (Not sure though).

Can any please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: The host is clearly resolving to something, otherwise you wouldn't get an HTTP500.  HTTP500 means there's some kind of internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to reach

www.simpaticorp.com

(taken from the dnsstuff.com URL), that website is up and reachable.  It's DNS seems to be configured correctly.

The error I see while browsing there is an HTTP 500, which means that the website has received the request for the homepage, but encountered an error while processing that request.

Check the Apache error logs to find more information on the error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I see this erro message in the erro log: SoftException in Application... UID script "/home/simpaticorp/public_html/index.php" is smaller than min_uid...

Comment: I guess this is related to permissions. can you help me with this

Comment: Post a new question with as much detail as possible.  I'm not an Apache guru, but if you post a link to your new question in a comment here, I'll have a look.